# Is there a way to extend a PyTables EArray in the second dimension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytables

I have a 2D array that can grow to larger sizes than I'm able to fit on memory, so I'm trying to store it in a h5 file using Pytables. The number of rows is known beforehand but the length of each row is not known and is variable between rows. After some research, I thought something along these lines would work, where I can set the extendable dimension as the second dimension.

```
filename = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'example.h5')
h5_file = open_file(filename, mode="w", title="Example Extendable Array")
h5_group = h5_file.create_group("/", "example_on_dim_2")
e_array = h5_file.create_earray(h5_group, "example", Int32Atom(shape=()), (100, 0)) # Assume num of rows is 100

# Add some item to index 2
print(e_array[2]) # should print an empty array
e_array[2] = np.append(e_array[2], 5) # add the value 5 to row 2
print(e_array[2]) # should print [5], currently printing empty array
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to add elements in this way (I might have misunderstood the way earrays work), but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're close...but have a small misunderstanding of some of the arguments and behavior. When you create the EArray with `shape=(100,0)`, you don't have any data...just an object designated to have 100 rows that can add columns. Also, you need to use `e_array.append()` to add data, not `np.append()`. Also, if you are going to create a very large array, consider defining the `expectedrows=` parameter for improved performance as the EArray grows.

Take a look at this code.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

filename = 'example.h5'
with tb.File(filename, mode="w", title="Example Extendable Array") as h5_file :
    h5_group = h5_file.create_group("/", "example_on_dim_2")
    # Assume num of rows is 100
    #e_array = h5_file.create_earray(h5_group, "example", Int32Atom(shape=()), (100, 0)) 
    e_array = h5_file.create_earray(h5_group, "example", atom=tb.IntAtom(), shape=(100, 0)) 
    print (e_array.shape)
    e_array.append(np.arange(100,dtype=int).reshape(100,1)) # append a column of values
    print (e_array.shape)
    print(e_array[2]) # prints [2]
```

Comment: Thank you! This clears things up a lot. Also just to confirm, Earrays could not support rows with variable lengths this way right?

Comment: Correct. AFAIK, EArrays don't support variable dimensions in any direction. You have to use a VLArray (Variable Length Array). They are documented on the Pytables site and there's an example here: [VLArray example](https://www.pytables.org/_modules/tables/vlarray.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how to create a **VLArray** (Variable Length). It is similar to the EArray example above, and follows the example from the Pytables doc (link in comment above). *However, although a VLArray supports variable length rows, **it does not have a mechanism to add items to an existing row** (AFAIK).*

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

filename = 'example_vlarray.h5'
with tb.File(filename, mode="w", title="Example Variable Length Array") as h5_file :
    h5_group = h5_file.create_group("/", "vl_example")
    vlarray = h5_file.create_vlarray(h5_group, "example", tb.IntAtom(), "ragged array of ints",) 

    # Append some (variable length) rows:
    vlarray.append(np.array([0]))
    vlarray.append(np.array([1, 2]))
    vlarray.append([3, 4, 5])
    vlarray.append([6, 7, 8, 9])

    # Now, read it through an iterator:
    print('-->', vlarray.title)
    for x in vlarray:
        print('%s[%d]--> %s' % (vlarray.name, vlarray.nrow, x))
```